# How to check if two arrays contain the same elements?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Is there any simple way to check if **two arrays contain the same elements**?

Here is my try were I return `true` if arrays are **not** the same:

```
arr1 := #(1 3 5 6).
arr2 := #(1 2 3 4).
arr2Copy := arr2 copyFrom: 1 to: arr2 size.
arr1 size ~= arr2 size
    ifTrue: [^ true].
arr1
    do: [:a | (arr2copy removeFirst = a)
        ifFalse: [^ true]].
^false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the elements should be **equal** and in the **same order**, you can just compare the arrays with **=**.

If the elements should be **equal** and the **order does not matter** and there are **no duplicates** to be expected, use `array1 asSet = arr2 asSet`.

Otherwise you can check out **hasEqualElements:**, and **asBag** as well.

If the elements should be **identical** and **in the same order**, how about this?

```
array1 with: array2 do:
    [ :a :b | a == b ifFalse: [ ^ false ]].
 ^ true
```

It iterates over the two arrays simultaneously, comparing the identities of elements at the same indices. If any are not identical, return false. If no distinct elements were encountered, return true.

Comment: Two objects can be equal (like arrays with the same contents), but they are still distinct instances and thus not identical. You check for identity with == and for equality with =.

Comment: SmallIntegers as used in your example are also identical when they are equal. The same does not hold for Strings, Points, and Rectangles, for example.

Answer (score 3):

As a side comment, please note that your code was almost right. Just change:

```
arr2Copy := arr2 copyFrom: 1 to: arr2 size.
```

with the following:

```
arr2copy := arr2 asOrderedCollection.
```

and your code will work. The reason is that you cannot `removeFirst` from an `Array`. This is why you need an `OrderedCollection` instead. (Note b.t.w. that there was a mismatch between the capitalizations of `arr2copy`).

Of course, this implementation is not as efficient as the one in the accepted answer, but I thought it might be useful to also give you some feedback about your approach.